# usando gatsby enviar formulario con axios a php

Tags: php, reactjs, formularios, axios, gatsby

tengo el problema de que se me esta resistiendo el envio de un formulario, según hago el envio por la web en su servidor las variables me imprimen vacias en cambio si lo hago por postman el envio se hace correctamente. No se si es algo de gatsby (llevo usandolo apenas un mes) o algo que me falla en el código. Adjunto los dos archivos

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

const AsideInfo = () => {

const [datos, setDatos] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    textarea:''
})

const handleInputChange = e => {
    setDatos({
        ...datos,
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
}

const enviarDatos = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: './contact.php', 
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>" },
        datos
    })
        .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log( error.message));

}


return ( 

    <div className="form">
        <form action="contact.php" method="post" onSubmit={enviarDatos}>

            <input type="text" name="name" value={datos.name} placeholder="Nombre" onChange={ handleInputChange }/>
            <input type="email" name="email" value={datos.email} placeholder="Email" required onChange={ handleInputChange }/>
            <textarea name="textarea" value={datos.textarea} rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" required onChange={handleInputChange}></textarea>
            
            <button id="sendMessageButton" type="submit"> Enviar </button>
        </form>
    </div>

 );
}

export default AsideInfo;
```

archivo contact.php. Aqui los var_dump me imprimen bien cuando uso postman pero me imprimen [] cuando lo hago desde la web

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['textarea'];

var_dump($name);
var_dump($message);

mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'De talleres xxxx', 'De: '.$name.' El mensaje ---> '.$message);
```

Esto es el console.log del resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te fijaste si del lado Cliente al momento de enviar la información está correcta?

Comment: Y otra cosa, el archivo .php dónde está alojado?

Comment: @Bélgica el archivo php está alojado en la raiz, añado la imagen del resultado de la llamada

Comment: Mmm y el 404 por qué? Te fijaste bien si el php está bien la ruta? Prueba montar un servidor con XAMPP por ejemplo, alojas tu contact.php en ese servidor y luego en la petición axios sería así: url: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/contact.php', Si no sabes como hacerlo me dices.